# Adding an ear to a volume inside docker on amazon ECS

Tags: java, amazon-ecs

When `docker run` on my local computer I can specify a volume with data. My volume contains my deployable ear that is required during runtime.

How i do that for an AWS ECS instance ?

I have tried creating a task definition with a volume but it doesn't include the java *.ear file that i need for run time. It creates an empty volume.

**docker-compose.aws.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
    my-jboss-app:
        # build: .
        image: my-jboss-app/my-app
        ports:
            - "8787:8787"
            - "8080:8080"
        environment:
            RUNTIME_ENV: prod
        volumes:
            - "$HOME/deployments:/opt/jboss/jboss-eap-7.0/standalone/deployments"
```

Comment: Can you at least give the relevant parts of the Task Definition? When you do it locally, are you doing it with `docker run -v`?

Comment: Do you mount the volume as a folder in host?

Comment: @JamieStarke yes i have a folder named deployments i'm i'm mounting trying to mount that volume. When i do it can't find it on ECS

Comment: @Ashan Yes. i have specified that in the task definition and i updated my original post.